# Split string data Using Regex in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I have String Like Following

```
string str=SCAN: SITE: http://www.vividinfotech.com SCAN: DOMAIN: www.vividinfotech.com SCAN: IP: 66.55.155.156 SYSTEM: NOTICE: Running on: ApacheRECOMMENDATIONS: 0: Security Header: X-XSS-Protection MissingRECOMMENDATIONS: 0: We did not find the recommended security header forXSS Protection on your site.
```

I need split the like SCAN and RECOMMENDATIONS  datas
as follows :

SCAN:

1.http://www.vividinfotech.com

2.DOMAIN: www.vividinfotech.com

3.IP: 66.55.155.156

is there any way do this

Comment: Please clarify your question..whats the expected result?

Comment: Do you need to *split* it or *extract* the parts?

Comment: extract the specified part 

1.http://www.vividinfotech.com

2.DOMAIN: www.vividinfotech.com

3.IP: 66.55.155.156

From SCAN part

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is using the following regular expression:

```
        string str = "SCAN: SITE: http://www.vividinfotech.com SCAN: DOMAIN: www.vividinfotech.com SCAN: IP: 66.55.155.156 SYSTEM: NOTICE: Running on: ApacheRECOMMENDATIONS: 0: Security Header: X-XSS-Protection MissingRECOMMENDATIONS: 0: We did not find the recommended security header forXSS Protection on your site.";
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"SCAN: SITE: (.*)SCAN: (DOMAIN:.*)SCAN: (IP: [\d\.]*)");
        if (m.Success && m.Groups.Count == 4)
        {
            string site = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string domain = m.Groups[2].Value;
            string ip = m.Groups[3].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wany a shorter way, you can use linq instead of regex. Something like:

```
string[] resultsSCAN = str.Split(new string[] { "SCAN: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Skip(1).Take(3).ToArray();
resultsSCAN[resultsSCAN.Count() - 1] = resultsSCAN.Last().Split(new string[] { "SYSTEM: " }, StringSplitOptions.None).First();
```

I think it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks lot 
Solved my problem.